# how can i deserialize json list with title name ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

When I return the model this way on Asp.Net Core Web Api :

`return Ok(menuBusiness.GetMenuList());`

everything is okey. But when I write the code with dictionary name or list title:

`return Ok(new { menuList = menuBusiness.GetMenuList() });`

I get an error:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Cannot
>   deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

I can't read the json. This is the code where I read the json:

```
public ViewViewComponentResult Invoke() {
    List < TitleViewModel > allmenulist = new List < TitleViewModel > ();
    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("inventorio");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"]);
    var response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/title/gettitlesbycompanyid");
    response.Wait();
    var result = response.Result;

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync < List < TitleViewModel >> ();
        readTask.Wait(); // I am getting the error this line
        allmenulist = readTask.Result;
    }

    return View(allmenulist);
}
```

When I tried to use asynchronous method I am not getting an error but the json looks as empty.

Comment: It sounds like the result is not an array, it is a single json object. When you say "I can't read the json" what do you mean? Use `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to get a look at what you are receiving. Also, you really should make the method async so you can `await` async calls.

Comment: Could you share your `/title/gettitlesbycompanyid` method and your model which could reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Crowcoder When I try to read json like this:                                                                   `code`[{"titleId": 1,"companyId": 1},{"titleId": 2,"companyId": 1}] I have no problem. But if the json like this:                                                                                       `code`{titleList:[{"titleId": 1,"companyId": 1},{"titleId": 2,"companyId": 1}]} How can I read the json for example, giving the method a "titleList" parameter.

Comment: @Rena  public IActionResult GetTitlesByCompanyId()
        {  List<GenTitle> title = titleBusiness.GetTitleListByCompanyId (usersBusiness.GetByToken(HeaderToken).CompanyId);
                    if (title.Count == 0)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(new { message = "no title" });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Ok(title); //What I want is: return Ok(new{titleList=title})                                                                                            
                    }}

Answer (score 1):

you can read response as a dynamic then read it's name property.

```
        public ViewViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        List<object> allmenulist = new List<object>();
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("inventorio");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"]);
        var response = client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress + "/title/gettitlesbycompanyid");
        response.Wait();
        var result = response.Result;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var d = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
            d.Wait(); // I am getting the error this line
            allmenulist = d.Result.name as List<TitleViewModel>;
        }

        return View(allmenulist);
    }
```